# vuejs route that calls filter function

Tags: vue.js

I've created a vuejs page that displays a list of articles at www.mydomain.com/articles.  These are filterable by a list of tags.  On click of the tag the custom filter is called and the articles update.  This works great.

I was now wondering if I can link to the prefiltered pages by declaring a route and pass the route argument into the filter?
I.e.  Accessing www.mydomain.com/articles/#/tag1 
will display the pre filtered list of articles tagged with 'tag1'

The VueJs router seems to talk about single page applications using the router but i'm hoping to link to the page from across my site.

Am I missing something or being dumb here? If so, sorry for asking.

Answer (score 1):

You would have one route that is the unfiltered articles, using a component named e.g. "Articles", and a second route, which also uses the articles component, but with a tag:

```
var Articles = Vue.extend({ ... })

var router = new VueRouter({root: '/articles'})

router.map({
  '/': {component: Articles } // matches '/articles/'
  '/:tag': {component: Articles } // matches '/articles/#/someTag'
})
```

Now in the template of that articles component, you can access `$route.params.tag`, which will contain the tag from the url (if there is one) and you can use that for the filter.